# file in C project: myproject.module

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I have a C project containing a file `myproject.module`. It looks like some sort of build/make file. I would like to know which toolchain can interpret this file and build the project.

The file looks like this:

```
% comments look like this

Config.h ILUV_MNMS

Message MNMS_OPEN
{ 
    int remaining;
}

AlterRules in myproject s/-c /-c -DSOME_OPTION /

Make.cc somefile
Make.cc anotherfile
Make.cc manymore

Make.cat myproj.o somefile.o anotherfile.o manymore.o ../llibc/llibc.o

Object myproj.o
{
    Executable myproj stack 8196
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a Virata configuration file.  You can load the file in vim and [detect](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html) the filetype by using `:set ft`.  The output for this file is:

```
  filetype=virata
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot find a toolchain called virata.